# Get XML items from numbered list using php/DOM ie <image number="1"> etc

Tags: php, xml, dom

just starting out with XML feeds and all going well so far but I have a problem with one feed

The XML is as so:

```
<Property>
<images>
<image number="1">
<image>http://www.blah.net/shared/depot/3168/biens/149506/images/627783.jpg
</image>
<image number="2"><image>http://www.blah.net/shared/depot/3168/biens/149506/images/627794.jpg</image>
</image>
<image number="3"><image>http://www.blah.net/shared/depot/3168/biens/149506/images/627792.jpg
</image>
</images>
</Property>
```

Using DOM and php, what should i use to access each of the image urls?

I'm using something like this for my other feeds but I can;t work out how to pick out the numbered items

I've tinkered with the code and googled without joy
Thanks
Tynan

```
$Pic1= $Property->getElementsByTagName('ImageURL1')->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: So you want to access the URLs for each image (between the <image> tags)?

Comment: the xml is broken. do you produce it?

Comment: michi, it's a chunk from a much larger block of xml, but what's wrong with it anyway? I had this working ok with simplexml but can;t work it out with DOM, I've freely admit I've been using it for a day

Comment: @tynan: paste your xml to http://www.xmlvalidation.com and see the error-message. `line 3`: you open `<image number="1">`, open a child-node named `<image>` as well on `line 4` ---> bad practice, you close that child-node on `line 5`, open another child of `line 3`, etc. If you are the autor of that xml, fix it first.

Comment: please consider to acceppt an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are the author of that XML, fix it first:
(I shortened your urls for easier formatting)

```
<Property>
    <images>
        <image number="1">http://www.blah.net/shared/627783.jpg</image>
        <image number="2">http://www.blah.net/shared/627794.jpg</image>
        <image number="3">http://www.blah.net/shared/627792.jpg</image>
    </images>
</Property>
```

Then, use simplexml to get the urls:

```
// $xmlstr holds the XML

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
urls = $xml->xpath("//image");
foreach ($urls as $url) echo "$url <br />";
```

See live demo of this code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VsvgJw

Comment: The xml isn't mine and I rather suspected it might be bad form to nest identical named tags and as said, I have had this working with simplexml but wanted to do it with DOM as I'm using that for all the other feeds and wanted to be consistent

So for fact that xml is bad? In that case I'll tell the client, I'd be having no problems with the 'fixed' version above, it was the nested <image> tags that were puzzling me, and for that matter still are as that's what I currently have to work with

Comment: I've worked around the problem by loading the problem feed with simplexml and getting hold of the image URLS with the following lines
  $Pic1 = $Property->images->image[1]->image;
  $Pic2 = $Property->images->image[2]->image;//etc
'code'$Pic1 = $Property->images->image[1]->image;
    $Pic1 = $Property->images->image[1]->image;
    $Pic2 = $Property->images->image[2]->image;//BS